# Turning off the async attribute in MediaWiki resource loader script tag

Tags: javascript, php, mediawiki

I have a dependency, and I think the asynchronous loading of MediaWiki resources (jQuery specifically) is causing a problem. Is there a way to switch off this attribute in a MediaWiki setting?[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by copying the structure of a jQuery dependency in `resources/Resources.php` with the resource I wanted to include and uploaded the `.js` file to the specified folder.

Then added the following code to `LocalSettings.php`:

```php
$wgHooks['BeforePageDisplay'][] = function( OutputPage &$out, Skin &$skin ) {
  $out->addModules('mymodule');
  return true;
};
```